# Exporting Data from Excel to SQL Server - VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, database

I know I can loop through the worksheet and add, row by row, data into SQL Server.

But I always wondered how dangerous could it be. Will I make the database (or even the server) slower? What are the impacts?

I also know that there are other methods, I just want to understand the limits of this specific one.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm talking about huge (thinking about the 1,4M rows of Excel limits) files 500k-800k rows and several columns.

Answer (score 0):

> But I always wondered how dangerous could it be. Will I make the database (or even the server) slower? What are the impacts?

- Any operation that you do in database will use the database resources and it will have some impact on the performance of the database. Sometimes the operation is so small or simple that the overall impact is negligible.
- The impact on database also depends on other queries being run either directly by users or as part of a query running via the actual application.
- You can check all the processes running and have a look at your query using the sp_who command.